# How to add a fixed background in Swift SpriteKit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm creating a motocross game with Swift using SpriteKit. So far I've added the player and the background to the scene. Everything looked good until I set the camera to follow the player. Now the background doesn't fit the screen anymore.

The code for my background looks like this:

```
func setupBackground() {

    for index in 1...2 {
        let background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "background1")
        background.size = self.size

        if index == 1 {
            background.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.position.y)
        } else {
            background.position = CGPoint(x: background.size.width, y: self.position.y)
        }

        background.name = "background"
        background.zPosition = -1000

        self.addChild(background)
    }
}
```

Is there a way to set the background to fit the screen even though the camera follows the player?

I searched the internet for a few hours but I couldn't find a solution for my problem. I hope some of you guys could help me.

**Edit:**

The background fits the screen but as soon as I activate the camera and set it to follow the player the background moves too. I want to fix the background so it fits the screen no matter where the camera moves...
Is there a way to achieve this?

The code for the camera looks like this:

```
func setupCamera() {
    playerCamera = SKCameraNode()
    self.camera = playerCamera
    playerCamera.position = player.position
    self.addChild(playerCamera)
}
```

And the update method looks like this:

```
override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {

    let action = SKAction.moveTo(CGPoint(x: player.position.x + player.frame.width * 2, y: player.position.y), duration: 0.15)
    playerCamera!.runAction(action)

}
```

Every setup method gets called by the following method which gets called by the didMoveToView method:

```
func setupScene() {
    setupCamera()
    setupBackground()
    setUpGround()
    setupControlls()

}
```

Comment: I am not sure what exactly you mean, but you could try this :        `background.size = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size` which makes the background the size of the entire screen

Comment: @Eric try what? :)

Comment: sorry I hit enter accidentally

Comment: @Eric That doesn't solve my problem... See my edit maybe then you'll know what I mean.

Comment: You question is insolvable like this :), please provide all the code, for example when the camera follows the player.

Comment: @Eric I hope this is enough? :)

Comment: Probably it is, but if you provide the code where the functions are executed (except for the update one of course) the change of your question being answered is bigger

Comment: Why don't you move the background with the same action you use for the camera?

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès I already thought about that but I thought there could be a better was...

Comment: What could be better?

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Well I thought there could be a property or some method which would fix the background but apparently there is none so I guess I have to move the background with the camera... Do you mind answering the question so I can accept it as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there is no concept of background in SpriteKit (that could have been very difficult to implement or define well as a scene is more or less an infinite world), you need to move your *background* node with the same action used for the camera.